# DSN-less connection to mysql server in ms-access not remembering user name and password

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, connection-string

For ease of distribution I want all the mysql linked tables to be DSN-less. I also want to be able to relink the tables to a different server easily (for test purposes), so I'm doing the link setup in vba code. This is the code I use to setup/refresh any links:

```
Private Sub relink_mysql_tables(mysql_connection As String)
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim tbldef As TableDef
    For Each tbldef In db.TableDefs
        If (tbldef.Attributes And TableDefAttributeEnum.dbAttachedODBC) Then
            tbldef.Connect = mysql_connection
            tbldef.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The mysql_connection string I use is:

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myusername;Pwd=mypassword;Option=3
```

This is all fine and dandy and everything works until I close ms-access and reopen it. The user name and password seems to get forgotten. If I try and open a linked table, for example, I'm presented with a ODBC Connector pop-up asking me to enter user name and password.

I notice that after running the above relink code that if I hover the mouse pointer over a linked table (a table called 'tender' in this instance) it shows the current connection string, but with the user name and password omitted:

```
ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Option=3;TABLE=tender
```

I read elsewhere that adding ";Persist Security Info=True" to the connection string would work but it doesn't! The user name and password is still forgotten the next time I restart ms-access. My current solution is to re-run the relink code every-time the database is started but this seems like an unnecessary overhead to me. Is the a way for access to remember the user name and password within the linked tables?

I'm using Mysql5.5 and Access2007 by the way.

Comment: I have mine setup to run the relink code every time the software is started up. As far as I know, this is the only solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer with the help of this [microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892490). Rather than using the RefreshLink method, delete and recreate the link with the dbAttachedODBC option:

```
Public Sub relink_mysql_tables(mysql_connection As String)

Dim db As Database
Dim tblDef As TableDef
Dim sLocalTableName As String
Dim sRemoteTableName As String    

' new collection '
Dim newTableDefs As New Collection

' current database '
Set db = CurrentDb()

' create new table defs '
For Each tblDef In db.TableDefs
    If (tblDef.Attributes And TableDefAttributeEnum.dbAttachedODBC) Then
        sLocalTableName = tblDef.Name
        sRemoteTableName = tblDef.SourceTableName

        ' create new linked table def '
        Set tblDef = db.CreateTableDef(sLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, sRemoteTableName, mysql_connection)
        newTableDefs.Add tblDef         

    End If
Next

' delete old table defs '
For Each tblDef In newTableDefs
    db.TableDefs.Delete tblDef.Name
Next

' add new table defs to current database '
For Each tblDef In newTableDefs
    db.TableDefs.Append tblDef
Next
```

The connection string is the same as before but with the addition of the prefix "ODBC;":

```
ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myusername;Pwd=mypassword;Option=3
```

Comment: I have never found it possible to update any kind of ODBC linked table, and always delete and recreate them as a matter of course whenever a change is necessary.

Comment: How to set this code? Could you please help to setup?