# MS Access Combo Box Not Getting Row Source Values

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

So I have this Access form that connects to a MySQL DB using a DAO connection  on the load event.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

    Set db = OpenDatabase("", False, False, Globales.ConnString)
    SQL = "SELECT tbl1Facturas.ID, tbl1Facturas.Fecha, tbl1Facturas.Localidad_ID, tbl5Localidades.NombreLocalidad, tbl1Facturas.Suplidor_ID, tbl6Suplidores.NombreSuplidor, tbl1Facturas.Factura, tbl1Facturas.Subtotal, tbl1Facturas.[Credito al Subtotal], tbl1Facturas.[CSA IVU MUNICIPAL], tbl1Facturas.[IVU MUNICIPAL], tbl1Facturas.[Credito IVU Municipal], tbl1Facturas.[CSA IVU ESTATAL], tbl1Facturas.[IVU ESTATAL], tbl1Facturas.[Credito IVU ESTATAL], tbl1Facturas.[Total de Compra], tbl1Facturas.[Exento al IVU ESTATAL], tbl1Facturas.[Metodo de Pago], tbl1Facturas.[ID Metodo Pago], tbl1Facturas.Factura_PDF, tbl1Facturas.MetodoPago_PDF, *" _
        & "FROM (tbl1Facturas INNER JOIN tbl5Localidades ON tbl1Facturas.[Localidad_ID] = tbl5Localidades.ID) INNER JOIN tbl6Suplidores ON tbl1Facturas.[Suplidor_ID] = tbl6Suplidores.ID;"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
    Set Me.Form.Recordset = rs
```

In that form I have a Combobox thats not getting the values from the Row Source property which I have it set up like this:

```
SELECT tbl5Localidades.ID, tbl5Localidades.NombreLocalidad FROM tbl5Localidades;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong there as this used to work when they were Access Tables but now that I moved the tables to a MySQL server the only thing thats not working are the comboboxes.

All help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128328/ms-access-with-mysql-linked-tables-not-getting-new-record) is still not solved?

Answer (score 0):

This code did it!

```
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL2 As String
    SQL2 = "SELECT tbl5Localidades.ID, tbl5Localidades.NombreLocalidad FROM tbl5Localidades;"
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(SQL2, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)

    With rs2
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
    Text18.AddItem !ID & ";" & !NombreLocalidad
    .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Is the ComBo's`Row Source Type` 'Table/Query' or 'Value List'?

Comment: With that code I use Value List since Table/Query doesnt work.

Comment: What is your RowSource Query (is data in Combos Query-Designer)? What column is bound. What column widths?

Comment: `Set db = OpenDatabase`is used to connect DSN-Less (Table is not linked)? Then [dsn-less-connection-to-mysql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695194/dsn-less-connection-to-mysql-server-in-ms-access-not-remembering-user-name-and-p)

Comment: I set the Row Source Type to Value List, the Bound Column to 1, the Column Counts to 2, and the Column Widths to 0",1". Also the query is "Select tbl5Localidades.ID, tbl5Localidades.NombreLocalidad FROM tbl5Localidades;" Using a DAO Recordset from current db.

Comment: Row Source Type must be  'Table/Query' or you can't use a 'Table/Query'. If your tables are not linked, you can assing your recordset with`Set ComboBox.RecordSet = rs2` (is the Combo realy named`Text18`?)